# Creating an Enviroment for plotly and matplotlib in python 2.7

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, plotly, conda

I managed to install on my conda the plotly package with:
conda install -c plotly plotly

And the matplotlib with:
conda create --name mpl33 python=3.3 matplotlib ipython-notebook

But I cant create one env with both of them inside because the plotly uses python 2.7 and matplotlib python 3.3

Thanks for the help!

Comment: does ``conda create --name mpl33 python=2.7 matplotlib ipython-notebook`` create a matplotlib for python 2.7? Maybe it is a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Installation

If you create a new environment, I would recommend using a new python version. Currently, I'd use python 3.6, because matplotlib does not support python 3.3 anymore.

So first create a conda environment with python 3.6; I name it `plotenv` here:

```
> conda create --name plotenv python=3.6
```

Next install matplotlib to it,

```
> conda install --name plotenv matplotlib
```

Finally install plotly to it,

```
> conda install --name plotenv -c plotly plotly
```

Done.

#### Console usage

Don't forget to activate the environment if you want to use it via `source activate plotenv` (on linux) or `activate plotenv` (on windows).

```
> activate plotenv
```

You may then start python

```
(plotenv) > python
```

and import any of the installed submodules, e.g.

```
>>> from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid
```

#### Usage with Jupyter

In case you want to use jupyter notebook with the newly created environment, you need to install it first,

```
> conda install --name plotenv ipython jupyter
```

and then run the following inside this environment:

```
(plotenv) > python -m ipykernel install --user --name plotenv
```

Now, starting juypter

```
(plotenv) > jupyter notebook
```

would give you the option to create a new notebook with this environment:

[image]

Comment: When i run :
 "conda create --name mpl33 python=3.3 matplotlib ipython-notebook" ,
"conda install -c anaconda pandas"

Then the matplotlib with mpl toolkit works fine

And when i install:

"conda create --name plotlyenv plotly plotly"

Then the part with plotly works fine

And then I tryed your code: 

"conda create --name plotenv python=3.6 plotly plotly pandas matplotlib"

And he cant find mpl toolkid , matplotlib module , although it is installed in the enviroment

I lost 6 hours trying to solve this....

Comment: Conda normally doesnt inspect submodules like mpl_toolkits. What exactly do you type where to get this error?

Comment: I expanded the answer to include everything up to an import of `mpl_toolkits`.

Comment: I ranned your code  in the anaconda prompt. And when I ran the code in my jupyter notebook : `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`  and `from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D`

I still got the error: **No module named 'matplotlib**

Comment: Are you sure the jupyter notebook is using the environment you just created or some other environment?

Comment: Nah, I doubt that. `ipython notebook` would probably just start the system wide notebook server without any option to change the environment. I updated the answer again with how to make sure to get the correct environment in juypter.