# Matplotlib not found

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have been trying to workout a matplotlib package. Even though it is installed and is show in conda list. I cannot import it in jupyter notebook

[image: packages]

[image: error]

Can't figure out any solution. Have already tried reinstalling the packages a couple of times

Comment: It looks like you have multiple python installations or multiple virtualenv, try installing matplotlib in the python environment used by jupiter.

Comment: ..or make sure to use the conda environment you installed matplotlib to in jupyter. [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50476501/creating-an-enviroment-for-plotly-and-matplotlib-in-python-2-7) would be helpful for that.